How can I implement a progressive data updation scheme based on the study levels of students in a particular year using Python and Django?
I am working on a project that is to handle students' level of education that is to be updated yearly as they move to another class in new year using python and django. Then render their academic progress on the student's profile page for each and evry year but my code is not rendering the information as it should.
This is how my code looks like
models.py
class AcademicProgress(models.Model):
    YEAR = (
        ('2023','2023'),
        ('2024','2024'),
    )
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=YEAR)
    bursaries =models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.student.studentName}'
    
    def update_progress(self, year, class_level):
        if year == 2023:
            self.year = class_level
        if year == 2024:
            self.year = class_level
        self.save()

def student_profile(request, pk):
    student = Student.objects.get(id=pk)
    academicprogress = AcademicProgress.objects.filter(student=student).first()
    examresults = ExamResults.objects.filter(student=student).select_related('exam')
    context = {'student': student,'academicprogress':academicprogress,'examresults':examresults}
    return render(request, 'profiles/student_profile.html', context)
def update_academic_progress(request, pk):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id=pk)

    # Get the academic progress instance or create one if it doesn't exist
    progress, created = AcademicProgress.objects.get_or_create(student=student)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            year = int(request.POST.get('year'))
            class_level = request.POST.get('class_level')

            # Make sure the class_level is valid before proceeding
            if not class_level:
                messages.error(request, 'Class level is required.')
                return render(request, 'add_templates/add_academic_progress.html', {'progress': progress, 'student': student})

            progress.update_progress(year, class_level)
            messages.success(request, 'Academic Progress saved successfully!')
            return redirect('student_profile', pk=pk)
        except ValueError:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid input for year.')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, f'An error occurred: {str(e)}')

    return render(request, 'add_templates/add_academic_progress.html', {'progress': progress, 'student': student})

student_profile.html
{% extends 'navbars/dataentrynavbar.html' %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .main{
        margin: 30px;
        padding: 25px;
        background: aqua;
        border-radius: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .profilepic{
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        
    }
    .progress{
        padding:40px; 
        background-color: aqua;      
    }

    
</style>
<div class="main">
            <img class="profilepic"style="align-items: center;" src="{{ student.profilePic.url }}" alt="studentProfilePhoto">
            <p>Student Name: {{ student.studentName }}</p>
            <p>Gender: {{student.gender}}</p>
            <p>Donor: {{ student.donor }}</p>
            <p>Intermediary: {{ student.intermediary}}</p>
            <p>Date of Birth: {{student.dateofbirth}}</p>
          BackGround Information:
                <p>{{ student.backgroundInfo }}</p>
                Date added : {{ student.date_added}}
            <h3>Academic Progress</h3>
            <table style="margin-top: 20px;" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Academic Year</th>
                    <th scope="col">Progress</th>                    
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>2023</td>
                    {% if academicprogress.year == 2023 %}
                    <td>{{ academicprogress.class_level }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td> </td>
                    {% endif %}
                    <td>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>2024</td>
                    {% if academicprogress.year.2024 %}
                    <td>{{ academicprogress.class_level }}</td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td> </td>
                    {% endif %}
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url 'update_academic_progress' student.id %}"class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  
            
              </table>
                    
            <h3>Exam Results</h3>
            <table style="margin-top: 20px;" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Exam</th>
                    <th scope="col">Subject</th>                    
                    <th scope="col">Score</th>                    
                    <th scope="col">Grade</th>                    
                    <th>Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
            {% if examresults %}
                {% for result in examresults %}
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ result.exam.exam_name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ result.subject}}</td>
                        <td>{{ result.score}}</td>
                        <td>{{ result.grade}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href=""class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>                        
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td>No Exam results Found</td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}                 
            
            </table>
            
         
</div>

{% endblock %}

